# Simultaneous selecting from tables and functions which use values from these tables

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have 3 tables: *lightnings*, *powerlines*, *masts*.

The main fields:

- `lightnings.geo_belief` - an ellipse of a probable hitting.
- `powerlines.geo_path` - a geo polyline of powerline's path.
- `masts.geo_coordinates` - a geo point of a mast placing.

**The task**:

1. To calculate lightning strokes that hit powerline's corridor (5000
   meters - its radius, and it is generated as a geometry by function
   `powerline_corridor()`)
2. To get info about a powerline's mast, nearest to a respective lightning hit and to get the **distance** from `lightning.geo_ellipse` to `masts.geo_coordinates`.

So I can select lightnings:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM lightnings l
JOIN ( SELECT geo_path, powerline_corridor(geo_path, 5000::smallint) AS geo_zone 
         FROM powerlines WHERE id=1)
   AS by_pl
   ON ST_Intersects(by_pl.geo_zone, l.geo_belief)
```

Also I have got the function `namos_nearest_mast(powerlines.id, lightnings.geo_belief)`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.namos_nearest_mast (
  powerline_id integer,
  geo public.geometry
)
RETURNS public.obj_powerline_masts AS
$body$
SELECT *
FROM obj_powerline_masts
WHERE powerline_id=$1
ORDER BY $2 <-> geo_coordinates ASC
LIMIT 1
$body$
LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

Couldn't you suggest good solutions for selecting?

Answer (score 1):

Following is all I've done by myself:

```
SELECT 
    t.*,
    ROUND(st_distance(namos_transform_meters(m.geo_coordinates), namos_transform_meters(t.geo_belief))) AS dist_m
FROM obj_powerline_masts AS m
JOIN
  (
    SELECT 
    l.*,
    (SELECT id FROM nearest_mast(1, l.geo_belief)) AS mast_id
    FROM lightnings l
    JOIN (SELECT geo_path, powerline_corridor(geo_path, 5000::smallint) AS geo_zone FROM powerlines WHERE id=1) AS by_pl ON ST_Intersects(by_pl.geo_zone, l.geo_belief)
    LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50
  ) AS t
  ON t.mast_id=m.id
```

But I'm not sure if it's an optimal solution. For instance, in PHP I can't apply dataProviders on such queries (which abstracts e.g. working with pagination), because of we can't affect on subqueries in a trivial way.